Determine Policy Changes in Noisy Medicare Insurance Claim Data
I am hoping that this is the right place to ask this and I will not get flamed for a poor question, but here goes.
Background:
I have a database of all Medicare claims (depersonalized) submitted in a five year period.
The database consists of 8.68B records.  Each record includes the day the claim was submitted, how much was sought, whether the claim was approved, for how much, and when.  Each record also categorizes the claim by one of ~22,000 codes (a CPT code) applicable to the procedure/device.  The data are sorted by these CPT codes, and within CPT codes, by date.
Whether a claim will be covered is subject to various policies affecting the relevant CPT code that I do not have access to.  Further, importantly for my questions, the policy applicable to a CPT code may change over time.  Something that was not covered may become so.  Something that was covered may no longer be.  And there could even be going back and forth, e.g., covered-not covered-covered.  Alternatively, the policy may never change in the database period.
Finally, the data is noisy.  While something may generally be covered, a claim may still be denied for various reasons, e.g., submitted late, not the required documents, etc.  Likewise, will something may generally be denied, it may still be covered, e.g., compassionate care.
Question:
Is there a method to detect these policy changes from the data itself, such that I could say that, for a given CPT code, the percentage of claims approved in one time period was X, while in a different period it was Y, etc.?
Another way of saying this might be: how would I figure out an appropriate window(s) and cut-off percentage to calculate the average approval rate in the face of this noisy data so that I can compare two time-series?
To be clear, I have a software background and am prepared to brute force things, i.e., try every possible window, if necessary.
Thanks for any help.

I don't think "time series" is a fitting lens through which to analyze here; you care about an effect for time, but not about how each outcome progresses from one claim to the next to the next.
You'll run separately (probably loop through) about 22,000 logistic regressions.  For each, you'll save key results:  coefficients for time; the p-value for time, i.e., for the model generally; and (probably) McFadden's pseudo-R-squared, as a measure of how much time matters to approval.
If you think policy changes have occurred year by year, then you would include dummy variables to separate time into years; you would treat time as a nominal, not an ordinal or continuous, variable.  If you think policy might change on a quarterly basis, then you would divide time into 20 quarters.  Alternately, you could probably set up splines to divide time into periods, but the first method would probably be cleaner, more interpretable, and more manageable.
Fun question.
EDIT:  Although you are seeking to learn about effects associated with time, you are not asking about the very granular time-related effects that would come under the aegis of time series analysis.  That type of analysis would include questions such as:

Does each approval/denial decision depend on the decision last made?  (Or the decisions from a day or a week ago?)
Does each approval become more (or less) likely  if following another approval?  I.e., do approvals come in "streaks"?
Can we forecast the outcome of a claim if we know what happened for the last few dozen?


Thank you very much for your thoughtful response.  I have been researching the concepts you mentioned and think I could probably, eventually, wrap my head around them.

I've gotten a scaled-down version of this to work in R.  9 billion records would require quite a bit of RAM, though.

I am still researching what "logistical regression" even is.  That said, I sorted the information and made ~22,000 individual files, one for each CPT code.  The most any one file has is ~512M records.  Further, I can store the data on an 8Tb SSD with 32GB RAM.
While this may be answered by my research, your comment about "time series" is confusing.  It would seem to totally depend on time.  Indeed, that is the whole issue:  how did coverage decisions change over time?
Although not discussed in my original question, ultimately, I intend to compare Medicare coverage to other insurance.

You needn't work with all 9B records to learn something useful from your data.  A random sample of 9M might be enough.

Thanks for your clarification. As I say, I am learning.  In terms of samples, of course you are correct.  Given our numbers, the average CPT code would have about 4M records.  That is a number that is small enough that I am thinking of just doing it and avoiding the added complexity of sampling.
